# Bond formations in doping of semiconductors

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, solid-state-chemistry, semiconductors

I was reading about semiconductors and found out that semiconductors are doped with either 13th group or 15th group elements which are named p-type and n-type semiconductors, respectively. In n-type semiconductors I found out about the following:

[image: N-type semiconductor]

Why does antimony form four bonds with silicon when it could just bond with three silicon atoms and have a lone pair instead of having an electron excited and have a free electron?